# i cannot import the library curses, i receive module _curses not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses, python-curses

if i try to "import curses" with python 3.9.6 installed i receive the message

```
"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" C:/Users/marco/PyCharm/Custom01/cursor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marco\PyCharm\Custom01\cursor.py", line 1, in <module>
    import curses
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

Can someone help me? What I've to do? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

- *try after installing windows-curses with:*

```
pip install windows-curses
```

Comment: i'll try but sorry should not be a python standard library installed by default?

Comment: On Linux and Mac `curses` comes as standard python library but on windows we have to install `window-curses` to make it work .

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. A strange choise it's not installed by default I think. I see however it doesn't work in Pycharm.